# Transform string into array of arrays, Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a string which looks like that:

```
[ [a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c] ]
```

I'd like to change it into an array of arrays.
Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: What you've quoted isn't a string. Please quote your *actual* input data. (And show your code where you've tried to convert it.)

Answer (score 0):

If your string is a valid JSON array, you could use `JSON.parse`:

```
var anArray = JSON.parse(arrayString)
```

Comment: The string quoted isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is actually like this (valid JSON):

```
var string = '[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]';
```

then you can do

```
console.log(JSON.parse(string));
```

> [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]

---

With

```
var string = "[[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c]]";
```

there is not much you can do as it isn't valid JSON, and `a,b,c` aren't defined. You will have to massage your "string" more to make it at least valid JSON.

Comment: I've made manipulation and now my variable looks exackly like this:
[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
but when I'm trying to do console.log(JSON.parse(string)); I'm getting a syntax error. Do you guys know that Internet Exploler 11 is supporting this comment?

Comment: Please open this jsbin, paste your string, and report what the console says: http://jsbin.com/labufo/1/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to split it on the "["-chars while ignoring the "]"-characters.

```
var str = "[[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c]]"
var splitted = str.split("[");
var outerArray = [];
for(var i in splitted){
    var token = splitted[i].replace(/]/g, "");
    if(token.length > 0){
        var innerArray = token.split(",");
        if (innerArray.length > 0)
            outerArray.push(innerArray);
    }
}
```

This is definitly not elegant, and may be prone to errors, due to unhandled whitespaces or empty strings. But this may be a way you could go...